# Gnome web browser stores downloaded files

Tags: debian, browser

I run Gnome Web Broser in Debian Lenny, but can't find place where it stores downloaded files. There is no place like `~/Downloads`. Where are my files?

Comment: Do you mean `gnome-www-browser`? If so, it puts downloaded files in `$HOME/Downloads`.  Make sure that you ran it as a regular user and not root.